# Am I supposed to have this message in my console while I'm trying to "see" my input fields?

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend, backend

can someone tell me why am I getting this message in my console while I'm trying to send my data to my backend but the only thing that I get when I fill the title (for instance: Hello) is :
:
SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: null, type: 'change', nativeEvent: InputEvent, target: input#title.p-1.border-2.mx-2.rounded-sm, …}

Plus, I'm not able to see the data from my Dropdown and my checkboxe I can see title and the date selected but not the checkbox and the Dropdown...

I was expected to get :

```
 {title:"H", date:"", choice: "", comment:""}
...
 {title:"Hello", date:"", choice: "", comment:""}
... ( after chosing the date and the choice):
 {title:"Hello", date:"2022-05-27", choice: true (if checkboxe is selected) comment: "Good"}...
```

Account:

```
export default function Account() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    title: "",
    date: "",
    choice: "", 
    comment:""
  });

  const COMMENT = [
    { label: "Good", value: "Good" },
    { label: "Medium", value: "Medium" },
    { label: "Bad", value: "Bad" }
  ];

  function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("", {
        title: data.title,
        date: data.date,
        choice: data.choice
        comment:data.comment
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    const newData = { ...data };
    newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newData);
    console.log(e);
  }
  function Checkbox({ value }) {
        const [checked, setChecked] = useState(value);
        return (
            <label>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={checked}
                    onChange={(e) => setChecked(checked => !checked)}
                    style={{
                        transform: "scale(1.2)",
                    }}
                />
                {value}
            </label>
        );
    }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
        <label>
          Comment :
          <Dropdown
            options={COMMENT}
            isMulti={false}
            value={data.comment}
            onChange={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
          />
        </label>
         Choice :  <Checkbox value={0} />    
          <label >
            Title:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={data.title}
              placeholder="Title"
              onChange={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
              id="title"
            />
          </label>
          <label >
            Date:
            <div>
              <input
                type="date"
                value={data.date}
                onChange={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
                id="date"
              />
            </div>
          </label>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

My goal is to be able when I click on 'Confirm' button (StepperControl.jsx) to send all the data to my api (and not each time i click on Next, but I'm aware that I will have to put an url, for now it will not work but that's fine, when i will give it one, it will work afterwards)

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-form-forked-pxzu99?file=/src/components/steps/Account.jsx)

Comment: Which console.log is this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you console.log the actual change event. Change `console.log(e);` in `handleSubmit` method to `console.log(newData)` to see the new data. Also to avoid confusion, I suggest to change this method name (`handleSubmit` method), as it is not a submit event handler but a change event handler - the submit method that sends the data is `onSubmit`.

Another issue I noticed - choice dropdown is not [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) so `data.choice` will never change.

Comment: @Bar17, do you know why I'm still not able to see the value selected for my dropdown and the checkboxe ? I can see the entered values for title and date but not comment and choice...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're `console.log`ing `e`. You need to `console.log` `data` or `newData` to get the output that you are looking for. `e` is the click event, so it shows all of the properties on the event (`target`, etc.), not the actual data.

Comment: it's workign better except for my dropdown and checkbox... I've edited the Dropdown but it still not working. Do you see why ?

Comment: @Zokulko, If you're talking about the "not found" error, you need to change the "../Dropdown" imports to "../CustomDropdown". Otherwise, the dropdown seems to be working when I test it on CSB.

Comment: I'm sorry I've not saved it, but why when I click on the checkbox and the dropdown, I can't see the selection in my console log ? I can see 2 things : title and date, but not choice and comment...

Comment: @Zokulko, the problem is that you're not calling `onChange` in the Dropdown component. Instead, you're passing `setSelected` as the `onChange` prop for `react-select`. `react-selects`'s `onChange` prop is different from normal events, so passing the same function will not work. You may need to find a different select component.